# can i restrict mongoose web server to not Accept http request but only from the host application

Tags: request, webserver, mongoose-web-server

Hi
I embedded the mongoose web server in my application it just showing bunch of web pages
I   opening port on localhost , but its mean I can send request from any ware in the network , this is something I like to prevent
Is there any way to tell the web server to Accept request only from the host application?

Answer (score 3):

At least in the standalone version of mongoose you can run it as
`mongoose -p 127.0.0.1:80`
to just listen on the localhost. hope that helps.

Comment: That is the correct answer. For embedded case, set listening_port option to "127.0.0.1:<port_number>"